# Is it possible to use something like an if statement in Firebase Bolt?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm wondering if there is anything similar to an `if` statement in bolt and if there is, how to use it?

Comment: That sounds a bit like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please edit your question to describe the use-case, the problem you have and what you've already tried. Seeing your JSON structure (as text, no screenshot) and existing (bolt) rules would go a long way towards an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Most likely, you're looking to use [functions](https://github.com/firebase/bolt/blob/master/docs/guide.md#functions) with the `||` and `&&` tags. But as Puf mentioned, we need to know what use case you're really trying to solve to make any effective recommendations.